# Stereo-Opticalflow with opencv and python, reconstruted 3D coordinate with cv.triangulatePoints

Tags: python, opencv, opticalflow, 3d-reconstruction

I am searching to create a script for Stereo-Opticalflow using OPENCV. My problem is reconstrution of cartesian coordinates using two images. i have two virtual cameras place at an angle 90° between cameras. i used cv.stereoCalibrate to calibrate but i don't know how to put back together the cartesian coordinate system. Can someone help me please ?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.